# jQuery plugin instances and remove/destroying them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in which a plugin that I have on the page will be references more than a few times. The issue is that the elements that will call the plugin will be created on the fly. And then removed etc... for instance.

1. I have a div structure and it creates some child elements.

i. I add the plugin instance on these children. They do some magic etc..

ii. User clicks a button, new set of child elements are created -- I create the plugin instances.

NOW -- what happens to those created in point "i" above? I am not using "widget" so I don't have the destroy method.

So, can I just call the child elements, and just loop thru them and destroy the data element etc.. ala.

```
$.each('[some_class_that_represents_all_elements]', function(a,b){
     $(b).data('PLUGIN_NAME') = null; // or
     delete $(b).data('PLUGIN_NAME'); // or
     $(b).data('PLUGIN_NAME', null);
})
```

If the elements are removed from the DOM, do the plugin instances also get removed/cleaned up?

Comment: So js is reference counted right, assuming nothing has a handle to your plugin it will get collected. I would use the profiler (Profiles tab) in chrome debugging tools and see whats what.

Comment: Check the plugin API documentation, see if it has a `.destroy()` method. Most of the jQuery UI widgets do, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery by default will cleanup any data you store using $(el).data() when you call the $(el).remove() method.

If you use $(el).detach() the data is preserved.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

> jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed
>   via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page.

Comment: I am not using data here BUT I am of the belief that jquery automatically stores the plugin reference in the data object. I want them gone when the dom elements are removed. I guess it would cleanup auto if that is the case, no?

Comment: It very much depends on the "plugin."  "jquery plugin" is frequently used as a synonym for "method added to jQuery.prototype."  What that method actually does is a wide-open question that need not have _anything_ to do with $(el).data() at all.

Comment: Yes, if they are stored in .data() they will be cleaned up automatically.